# Can't authenticate to Aurora Db in AWS VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-aurora

I've recently setup a VPC on AWS with a EC2 instance and an Aurora RDS. I've assigned security groups and SSH connections with EC2 and connection to RDS seems to work but I cannot authenticate. The error is:

```
    mysql -h <clustername>.cluster-cd00tic6zepk.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -u <master user> -p –P3306
    ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'xxx'@'10.0.0.104' (using password: YES)
```

I've also tried connecting via PHP, similar error:

```
Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user xxx@'10.0.0.46' (using password: YES)
```

The application server lives on a public subnet and the rds is on a private subnet, not accessible except by the application server... If that makes a difference.

Most of the tutorials and forums show an instance name instead of IP address when connecting to RDS, is this why I can't authenticate? I believe all of the security groups are good because I can connect, is this an issue with Aurora?

Comment: Are you running above command from Ec2 instance or your local?

Comment: From EC2 instance, thats the only allowed connection to db

Comment: Can you add a space here "-P 3306" and then try?

Comment: Tried, same error:

Comment: Does your Private subnet which has the RDS has a Internet connection through NAT?

Comment: nope, doesn't need one as far as I know? I don't plan on any internet connectivity from this subnet.

Comment: i replicated above use case in my AWS account and I was successfully able to connect the Aurora I guess there is some issue with the username and password you are using. Can you try resetting the password and then try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I ended up deleting and recreating the RDS instance and everything worked as expected.